# getvalue from FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridviewcolumn, frameworkelementfactory

Am having a list view with one GridViewColumn

```
        GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();

        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory ch = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));

        Binding bind= new Binding("Empty");
        ch.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, bind);

        dt.VisualTree = ch;
        gvc.CellTemplate = dt;
        (lv.View as GridView).Columns.Add(gvc);
```

later when I want to retrieve whether the checkbox is checked or not am facing the **FrameworkElementFactory**, as it has no GetValue method, didn't know ho to cast it to a checkbox, so how can I get the IsChecked property from a **FrameworkElementFactory**, knowing that am able to access to it for any element of my listview

```
 ...
var mycheckboxFEF = template.VisualTree.FirstChild;// FirstChild is my FrameWorkElementFactory checkbox
bool isempty= (......) ????
```

Comment: Does the listview have a collection bound to it via ItemsSource ?

Comment: Yes my listview have a collection bound to its `ItemsSource`

Comment: So,why can't you retrieve the value that makes your `CheckBox` checked/unchecked from the collection ?

Comment: I've only binded the CheckBox.Text Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did provide a solution to your problem through this exemple.

This should work by selecting an item and pressing the button 
 XAML :

```
<Button Margin="0,12,401,276" Click="Button_Click">Button</Button>
        <ListView x:Name="yourListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Things}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing}" Margin="0,41,0,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Check"  Width="250">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="myCBox" Content="{Binding ThingName}"></CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Code behind :

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Things = new List<Thing>
                         {
                             new Thing {ThingName = "t1"},
                             new Thing {ThingName = "t2"},
                             new Thing {ThingName = "t4"},
                             new Thing {ThingName = "t3"},
                         };
            DataContext = this;

        }

        public List<Thing> Things { get; set; }
        public Thing SelectedThing { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var yourListViewItem = (ListViewItem)yourListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(yourListView.SelectedItem);
            CheckBox cb = FindByName("myCBox", yourListViewItem) as CheckBox;
            MessageBox.Show(cb.Content + " IsChecked :" + cb.IsChecked);
        }
        private FrameworkElement FindByName(string name, FrameworkElement root)
        {
            Stack<FrameworkElement> tree = new Stack<FrameworkElement>();
            tree.Push(root);

            while (tree.Count > 0)
            {
                FrameworkElement current = tree.Pop();
                if (current.Name == name)
                    return current;

                int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                    if (child is FrameworkElement)
                        tree.Push((FrameworkElement)child);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }



    public class Thing
    {
        public string ThingName { get; set; }

    }
```

Hope it helps